# reading inline table from macro

Tags: pgfplots

For a patch plot I need to read the patch table from a previously defined macro `\mytable`. However this results in an error:

> ```
>  ! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the choice 'row sep=crcr' is currently only av
> ailable for inline tables, not for external files.
>
> See the pgfplots package documentation for explanation.
> Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
>  ...                                              
>
> l.15 ...s { (0,0) (1,1) (2,0) (3,1) (2,0) (4,0) };
>
> ?
> ```

The failing document with inline table from macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
\def\mytable{
0 1 2 100\\
1 2 3 10\\
4 3 5 0\\}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
% this uses per-patch color data:
\addplot[patch,table/row sep=\\, patch table with point meta=\mytable]
coordinates { (0,0) (1,1) (2,0) (3,1) (2,0) (4,0) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

The working example with in inline table reads

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
% this uses per-patch color data:
\addplot[patch,table/row sep=\\, patch table with point meta={
  0 1 2 100\\
  1 2 3 10\\
  4 3 5 0\\
}]
coordinates { (0,0) (1,1) (2,0) (3,1) (2,0) (4,0) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How do I have to modify the first code to produce the same result as with the second code?

Comment: You cannot read the table from a macro.  You have to expand the macro inside of the options.  This is done by using `\edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot[...] ...;}\temp`.  Unfortunately, here ``\\`` will bite you, as it will be expanded as well.

Comment: Did the trick of Henri help you to solve your problem or do you need further assistance?

Comment: Thank you @Stefan for returning to this topic. No, actually, Henri's suggestion did not work for me. As a workaround, I write the patch table data into a temporary file which is read-in by the `\addplot` command. This works well, but a solution without the need for auxiliary files would still be welcome.